# Using Model Relationship in a Single Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Consider the following:

```
$posts = $this->model->newQuery()
    ->whereIn('user_id', $user->following) // specifically this line
    ->orWhere('user_id', $user->id)
    ->get();
```

The problem with the above is that there are two queries:

- Get following: `$user->following`
- Get posts: Above

This would be much more efficient with the use of a subquery, however, I cannot actually remember the correct way to do it...

I have tried all of the following:

```
// This was a long-shot...
...->whereIn('user_id', function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->raw($user->following()->toSql());
});

// This works but pretty sure it can be done better with eloquent...
...->whereIn('user_id', function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->select('follow_id')
        ->from('user_follows')
        ->where('user_id', $user->id);
});
```

Is there a way that this can be achieved by using the previously defined relationship `$user->following()` instead of manually defining the relationship query like the last example above?

## Reference

The `following` relationship is defined as follows:

```
/**
 * Get the users that the user follows.
 */
public function following()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('SomeApp\User\Models\User', 'user_follows', 'user_id', 'follow_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: Please add the `following` relationship.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir See amendment :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
->whereIn('user_id', $user->following()->getQuery()->select('id'))
```

Comment: Fantastic, that’s exactly the sort of thing I was looking for! Not able to test now as no longer at my computer but will test and accept first thing tomorrow. Thank you!